# Installing and setting up SVN on FreeBSD Server

Tags: svn, freebsd, bsd

Firstly thank you to everyone who responded to my earlier question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393827/setting-up-svn-web-based-services-vs-your-own-svn-server

As much as I would prefer to use a web based solution, the svn server is to be implemented in the office.

We are currently running FreeBSD on our server, I am currently looking for information on setting up a SVN repository on the server with the command prompt.

I have used terminal commands on Ubuntu in the past so I have some idea but I am nowhere near a expert. I have come across a handful of tutorials however they seem quite different and seem to skip a few bits. Im really looking for a step by step guide on setting up a repository and its users. Ideally a beginners guide so I know exactly whats happening.

I would really appreciate any hints or pointers in the right direction.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6):

I advise you at first try to use svnserve daemon which comes with subversion. It uses its own protocol over TCP, so for all operations with repository you'll be using a svn:// URL scheme, for example:

```
% svn checkout svn://localhost/myproject
```

So, after installing devel/subversion port:

```
# cd /usr/ports/devel/subversion
# make WITHOUT_BDB=1 WITH_SVNSERVE_WRAPPER=1 WITH_REPOSITORY_CREATION=1 install clean
```

you will get a fresh empty repository in `/home/svn/repos`. The Port also will create `svn` user and `svn` group (check for both of them in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` files to be sure).

Then, add this lines to yous `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
svnserve_enable="YES"
svnserve_flags="-d --listen-port=3690 --listen-host 127.0.0.1"
svnserve_data="/home/svn/repos"
svnserve_user="svn"
svnserve_group="svn"
```

Change 127.0.0.1 to another IP, accessible from other machines, if you need that.
Start daemon with the command:

```
# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/svnserve start
```

If no errors occurred, check running daemon:

```
# /usr/local/etc/rc.d/svnserve status
svnserve is running as pid 65968.
```

or

```
# sockstat | grep svn
svn      svnserve   65968 3  tcp4   127.0.0.1:3690        *:*
```

OK. Now you'll need to create a per-user authentication for svnserve. This is done by editing `/home/svn/repos/conf/passwd` file, for example:

```
[users]
bob = password
joe = another_password
alex = yet_another_password
```

Then, make sure that in `/home/svn/repos/conf/svnserve.conf` file exists this lines:

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

That's it. Now you can import your sources into this repository. For more information *please read* http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html

Comment: just a note, im not sure why, but the installer for me used the user 'www' and group 'www'

Answer (score 3):

[Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com) is the source I usually turn to for Subversion information. Chapters 5 and 6 look like they might get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ su -
$ cd /usr/ports/devel/subversion
$ make install clean
```

Answer the questions asked during installation, and you should get a working subversion installation.

If you don't get the dialog asking for configuration options type

```
$ make config
```

To allow enabling the apache module, svnserve and a few other options.

Comment: But no server, as far as I know...

Answer (score 2):

I recommend accessing the repository with HTTP, which will simplify many things for the clients (specially if they are behind a firewall). I like going [the Apache way](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html).

Answer (score 1):

The latest version is available as port and [pre-built package](https://www.freshports.org/devel/subversion/).

To install the package,

```
sudo pkg install subversion
```

And make sure to read and follow the text with details.